# Is there a way so I can use absolute paths in SCSS using vite?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, absolute, vite

so I'm trying React + Vite, because webpack is kinda slow for me. Now I'm trying to set up a project starter, but I can't make SCSS files to use absolute paths. I added vite-tsconfig-paths to my vite.config.ts file, absolute paths works within typescript files, but while I'm trynna use it in SCSS it doesn't work. When I do write it like this:

```
@use 'styles/colors' as *;

.mainPageContainer {
    h1 {
        color: $clr-text-dark;
    }
}
```

it doesn't work and I get following
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl7lC.png) message.
Like this:

```
@use '../styles/colors' as *;

.mainPageContainer {
    h1 {
        color: $clr-text-dark;
    }
}
```

works. But I kinda want it to be absolute.

Spent too much time searching, nobody mentions this, did anyone encounter such a problem and fixed it?

Comment: Both are relative paths. The first one is the same as `./styles/colors`, which we know based on your second example that is not the correct path. If you need it to be “absolute” then look into creating an alias for it: Vite has added support for it since 2021 https://github.com/vitejs/vite/commit/82d87d91048b90282c4cae079ee142deb2a782d5

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it, tho in project, where I use Webpack I can do @use 'styles/colors' and wherever I am it's exported from src/styles/_colors.scss, so that led me to conclusion that without './' it's absolute.

In scenario with webpack it resolves module, but vscode doesn't understand it, while I ctrl + click on 'styles/colors' it tell's me the file does not exist, tho react and webpack resolves it correctly. Idk why it is like this

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments above, while the `vite-tsconfig-paths` plugin doesn't cover this, you can use a vite alias alongside that plugin for absolute sass imports:

```
// vite.config.ts

export default {
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths(), react()],
}
```

```
// styles.scss

@use '~/scss/functions' as *;
```